# What are some tips to make a function with a lot of calculation clean?

Tags: c++, oop, function, coding-style

How can functions like this:

```
void Map::Display()
{
    if(initialized)
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        int hScrollPos = GetScrollPos(M_HWnd, SB_HORZ);
        int vScrollPos = GetScrollPos(M_HWnd, SB_VERT);

        D2D1_RECT_F region = {0,0,TILE_WIDTH,TILE_HEIGHT};
        D2D1_RECT_F tFRegion = {0,0,TILE_WIDTH,21}; // tile front's region
        Coor coor;
        int tileHeight;

        RECT rect;
        GetWindowRect(M_HWnd, &rect);
        int HWndWidth = rect.right - rect.left;
        int HWndHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;


        pRT->BeginDraw();

        pRT->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(0.45f, 0.76f, 0.98f, 1.0f));

        pRT->SetAntialiasMode(D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_ALIASED);
        for(int x=0; x<nTiles; x++)
        {
            coor = ppTile[x]->Getcoor();
            tileHeight = ppTile[x]->Getheight();

            pRT->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());

            if((coor.GetX() - 1) * (TILE_WIDTH * 0.5) - hScrollPos > 0 - TILE_WIDTH &&
                (coor.GetX() - 1) * (TILE_WIDTH * 0.5) - hScrollPos < HWndWidth &&
                ((coor.GetY() - 1) * (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.5) * 1.5f) + ((MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - tileHeight) * (TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)) + TILE_HEIGHT - vScrollPos > 0 - (TILE_HEIGHT * 2.5) &&
                ((coor.GetY() - 1) * (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.5) * 1.5f) + ((MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - tileHeight) * (TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)) + TILE_HEIGHT - vScrollPos < HWndHeight)
            {
                /* Draws tiles */
                pRT->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(
                    (coor.GetX() - 1) * (TILE_WIDTH * 0.5) - hScrollPos,
                    ((coor.GetY() - 1) * (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.5) * 1.5f) + ((MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - tileHeight) * (TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)) + TILE_HEIGHT - vScrollPos
                    ));

                pRT->FillRectangle( &region, pBmpTileBrush[ppTile[x]->GetType() + 1]);

                /* Draws tiles' front */
                if((coor.Y - 1) / 2 < mapSizeY - 1) // If we are not in the front row,
                {
                    if(coor.X > 1)
                    {
                        for(int diffH = tileHeight - ppTile[x + mapSizeX - 1]->Getheight(); diffH == 0; diffH--)
                        {
                            pRT->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());

                            pRT->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(
                                (coor.GetX() - 1) * (TILE_WIDTH * 0.5) - hScrollPos,
                                ((coor.GetY() - 1) * (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.5) * 1.5f) + ((MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - tileHeight) * (TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)) + TILE_HEIGHT - vScrollPos  + (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.75) + (diffH * TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)
                                ));

                            pRT->FillRectangle( &tFRegion, pBmpTileFrontBrush[ppTile[x]->GetType()]);
                        }
                    }

                    if(((coor.X -1) / 2) + 1 < mapSizeX)
                    {
                        for(int diffH = tileHeight - ppTile[x + mapSizeX]->Getheight(); diffH == 0; diffH--)
                        {
                            pRT->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());

                            pRT->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(
                                (coor.GetX() - 1) * (TILE_WIDTH * 0.5) - hScrollPos,
                                ((coor.GetY() - 1) * (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.5) * 1.5f) + ((MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - tileHeight) * (TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)) + TILE_HEIGHT - vScrollPos  + (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.75) + (diffH * TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)
                                ));

                            pRT->FillRectangle( &tFRegion, pBmpTileFrontBrush[ppTile[x]->GetType()]);
                        }
                    }

                    if(coor.X == 1 || (coor.X - 1) / 2 == mapSizeY - 1) // If the tile if at any of left or right edge,
                    {
                        for(int n = ((TH * 1.5) / TPPL) - (ppTile[x + mapSizeY + mapSizeY - 1]->Getheight() - tileHeight); n>=0; n--)
                        {
                            pRT->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());

                            pRT->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(
                                (coor.X - 1) * (TILE_WIDTH * 0.5) - hScrollPos,
                                ((coor.Y - 1) * (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.5) * 1.5f) + ((MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - tileHeight) * (TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)) + TILE_HEIGHT - vScrollPos  + (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.75) + (n * TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)
                                ));

                            pRT->FillRectangle( &tFRegion, pBmpTileFrontBrush[ppTile[x]->GetType()]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                else // If we are in the front row
                {
                    for(int h = tileHeight; h >= 0; h--)
                    {
                        pRT->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());

                        pRT->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(
                            (coor.GetX() - 1) * (TILE_WIDTH * 0.5) - hScrollPos,
                            ((coor.GetY() - 1) * (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.5) * 1.5f) + ((MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - tileHeight) * (TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)) + TILE_HEIGHT - vScrollPos  + (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.75) + (h * TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER)
                            ));

                        pRT->FillRectangle( &tFRegion, pBmpTileFrontBrush[ppTile[x]->GetType()]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        pRT->SetAntialiasMode(D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_PER_PRIMITIVE);

        hr = pRT->EndDraw();
    }
}
```

this:

```
Tile* Map::GetClickedTile(short xPos, short yPos)
{
    Tile* pNoClickedTile = NULL;
    int hScrollPos = GetScrollPos(M_HWnd, SB_HORZ);
    int vScrollPos = GetScrollPos(M_HWnd, SB_VERT);

    if(xPos < (mapSizeX * TILE_WIDTH) - hScrollPos) // If the click is within width of the map then...
    {
        Coor coor;
        int height;
        int currentTile;
        int tileDistanceFromTop;


        /* Checks if click is in an odd row of tiles */
        int column = (xPos + hScrollPos) / TILE_WIDTH;

        for (int y=mapSizeY-1; y>=0; y--)
        {
            currentTile = column + (y * (mapSizeX+mapSizeX-1));

            coor = ppTile[currentTile]->Getcoor();
            height = ppTile[currentTile]->Getheight();

            tileDistanceFromTop =   ((coor.Y / 2) * TILE_HEIGHT * 1.5f) + // Distance between two tiles
                                    ( (MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - height) * TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER) -
                                    vScrollPos +
                                    SPACE_LEFT_FOR_BACKGROUND;

            /*if (tileDistanceFromTop < 0)                               // If the tile is partially hidden,
                tileDistanceFromTop = tileDistanceFromTop % TILE_HEIGHT;     // then % TILE_HEIGHT*/

            if( yPos > tileDistanceFromTop &&
                yPos < tileDistanceFromTop + TILE_HEIGHT)
            {   
                /* Get relative coordinates */
                int rpx = xPos % TILE_WIDTH;
                int rpy =   ( (yPos - SPACE_LEFT_FOR_BACKGROUND) - 
                            (y * (TILE_HEIGHT /2) ) -
                            ( ( MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - height) * TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER) +
                            vScrollPos) %
                            TILE_HEIGHT;

                /* Checks if click is withing area of current tile */
                if (rpy + (rpx / (TILE_WIDTH /16)) > TILE_HEIGHT * 0.25f &&     // if click is Down Right the Upper Left slope and,
                    rpy + (rpx / (TILE_WIDTH /16)) < TILE_HEIGHT * 1.25f &&     // it is UL the LR slope and,
                    rpy - (rpx / (TILE_WIDTH /16)) < TILE_HEIGHT * 0.75f &&     // it is UR the LL slope and,
                    rpy - (rpx / (TILE_WIDTH /16)) > TILE_HEIGHT * -0.25f)      // it is DL the UR slope,
                        return ppTile[currentTile];                             // Then return currentTile
            }
        }


        /* Checks if click is in an even row of tiles */
        column = (xPos + hScrollPos - (TILE_WIDTH/2)) / TILE_WIDTH;

        for (int y=mapSizeY-2; y>=0; y--)
        {
            currentTile = column + (y * (mapSizeX+mapSizeX-1)) + mapSizeX;

            coor = ppTile[currentTile]->Getcoor();
            height = ppTile[currentTile]->Getheight();

            tileDistanceFromTop =   (((coor.Y - 1) / 2) * TILE_HEIGHT * 1.5f) + // Distance between two tiles
                                    ( (MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - height) * TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER) +
                                    (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.75) -
                                    vScrollPos +
                                    SPACE_LEFT_FOR_BACKGROUND;

            /*if (tileDistanceFromTop < 0)
                tileDistanceFromTop = tileDistanceFromTop % TILE_HEIGHT;*/

            if( yPos > tileDistanceFromTop &&
                yPos < tileDistanceFromTop + TILE_HEIGHT)
            {   
                /* Get relative coordinates */
                int rpx = xPos % TILE_WIDTH;
                int rpy = (int)((yPos - SPACE_LEFT_FOR_BACKGROUND) - 
                                (y * (TILE_HEIGHT /2) ) -
                                ( ( MAX_MAP_HEIGHT - height) * TILE_PIXEL_PER_LAYER) -
                                (TILE_HEIGHT * 0.675) +
                                vScrollPos) %
                                TILE_HEIGHT;

                /* Checks if click is withing area of current tile */
                if (rpy + (rpx / (TILE_WIDTH /16)) > TILE_HEIGHT * 0.25f &&     // if click is Down Right the Upper Left slope and,
                    rpy + (rpx / (TILE_WIDTH /16)) < TILE_HEIGHT * 1.25f &&     // it is UL the LR slope and,
                    rpy - (rpx / (TILE_WIDTH /16)) < TILE_HEIGHT * 0.75f &&     // it is UR the LL slope and,
                    rpy - (rpx / (TILE_WIDTH /16)) > TILE_HEIGHT * -0.25f)      // it is DL the UR slope,
                        return ppTile[currentTile];                             // Then return currentTile                      // Then return currentTile
            }
        }
    }
    return pNoClickedTile;
}
```

Or even this:

```
int Map::GetTileNByCoor(Coor coor)
{
    return ((coor.X / 2 + ((coor.Y - 1) * mapSizeY) - (coor.Y / 2));
}
```

be made easier to read? As my code grows bigger, I realize how important, if not at times necessary, it is to have a clean, easy to read code. What are some tips to make codes like the ones above cleaner?

Comment: I think this question belongs on [CodeReview.SE]. I've flagged to ask a moderator to take a look at it and see if they agree with me, because that's one of the standard migration paths.

Comment: I didn't know there existed code review, but I guess you are right. My question rather belongs there.

Answer (score 4):

My general refactoring practices is usually to do the following:

1. Pull out names for things that aren't apparent in the code.  You can use local variables to give defining names to small pieces of code.  So, in cases like your last example, what does `(coor.X / 2 + ((coor.Y - 1) * mapSizeY)` represent?

   In most cases its better to have things names well, than worry about storing local variables (they will be deleted when the stack leaves the function, and usually you are not going to be too worried about memory space/speed of the code at such a fine grain).
2. Pull out groups of executing code into methods.  A good rule of thumb is if your function is more than 6 lines of code, you can probably pull out a smaller function inside of it.  Then your code will read better to what it's actually doing.

   A very common place to look at this is loops.  You can almost always pull the code inside a loop into it's own function, with a good descriptive name.
3. After you have pulled out methods, you can group common shared functionality into smaller objects.  It's almost always better to have smaller objects working together to do the work, than to have giant objects that do a lot of work.  You want your objects to each have a single responsibility.

Comment: Good general advice. Regarding the second paragraph of your #1, almost all modern compilers are smart enough to optimize temporary variables out entirely whenever possible. That's yet another reason you shouldn't worry about the performance of your code, but instead on *readability*.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty solid code, well done.  I would consider:

- Comment the function itself at a high-level, and then add better comments for all the significant blocks in the code, and for anything unusually tricky.
- Use descriptive consts or #defines for all the magic variables you're using.  Why multiply by 0.675?  What does 0.675 represent?  Ditto 0.25, 1.25, -0.25 etc.
- Turn things like the "Checks if click is withing area of current tile" test (and others) into a separate method that you call, for example isClickInsideTile(x,y,tile).
- Add debug trace so that the next person responsible can enable debug to get diagnostics.

PS good job with your variable names and method names.

Comment: Definitely need to get rid of the magic numbers. There's no quicker way to zap readability of code. Make them constants, either at local or global scope, depending on when they're needed. The runtime cost will be none.